# Redirect Loop on older Browsers?

Tags: loops, mod-rewrite, redirect, browser

My **website is working fine on most modern browsers** (FF, Chrome, IE, Opera, Safari).

But on some **older browsers, I get a "this webpage has a redirect loop" error** message.

I checked the website with different status code checkers and there seems to be no error: Clean 301->200 redirects to the startpage.
This is the modrewrite condition I use to redirect both www and http request to the https://example.com startpage.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

How is this possible? What could cause this behavior? 
Thank you!

Browser list causing of browser reporting a redirect loop:
Android Browser 4.4, Opera 20-26, Chrome 26-36, FF 30

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I don't know why the original redirect didn't work. But here is a different solution that does the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```